# DDoS con ajax y bucles For/While

Tags: javascript, ajax, bucle-for

**¿Es posible realizar un DDoS con peticiones ajax?** 
en mi página cuando utilizo `console.log()` quise ver los resultados que traía y corroborar de que todo funcione en bien, **hasta que se me ocurrió la idea de utilizar un ciclo `for`**, acto seguido probé a ver que pasaba y mi página se congelo totalmente. 
Nose si es porque se realizó de manera local y se congelo culpa del for **o si se congeló el servidor por hacer tantas peticiones ajax**

si se congeló el servidor, hay métodos de seguridad para prevenir estos ataques? desdes ya Gracias

Comment: Se te congeló la página, no el servidor. Es un problema de tu navegador que no afecta a nada más que a esa pestaña

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar hacer un DoS desde tu propio pc en local (Denial of Service) pero los navegadores limitan el número de conexiones simultáneas que puedes realizar:
[image: Máximo de conexiones simultáneas]

Como se ve en la imagen, la séptima petición no empieza hasta que termina alguna de las anteriores 6.

Imagen sacada de [StackOverflow @PSK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015472/concurrent-ajax-requests-in-chrome/55117694).

Aquí podemos ver una tabla con el máximo de conexiones que permiten los navegadores:
[image: Tabla de conexiones máximas]

La tabla está sacada de [aquí](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html)

Por supuesto hay maneras de "sobrepasar" esos límites, uno de ellos es tener subdominios, ya que cada subdominio contará con su propio límite.

Comment: -1 Eso es **totalmente falso**. Son **los navegadores** los que imponen un límite, el HTTP por si mismo **es imposible que lo haga**. El límite se puede imponer en el servidor mediante configuración, o en el propio SO. Y es imposible limitar un ataque coordinado desde varias máquinas. Esta respuesta da una falsa sensación de seguridad.

Comment: Correcto, @Juanjo, cuando dije que el límite era del http me refería a cómo estaba implementado dicho protocolo, obviamente el protocolo en sí se encarga unicamente de la conexión. Lo siento si mi explicación daba a entender otra cosa.

Comment: Tambien cabe decir que algunos navegadores permiten abrir más conexoines en simultáneo (ej. Firefox, modificando parámetros en about:config)